# How to encode Intervals with pd.LabelEncoder? TypeError: unorderable types: Interval() < float()

Tags: python, pandas

I have two features in my Dataset which consist of interval values: AgeBand and FareBand.

[image]

I want to encode these with numeric categories using the `pandas.preprocessing.LableEncoder`, but stumble upon this issue.

```
le = LabelEncoder()

for df in [df_train, df_test]:
    df['IsAlone'] = le.fit_transform(df['IsAlone'])
    df['AgeBand'] = le.fit_transform(df['AgeBand'])
    df['FareBand'] = le.fit_transform(df['FareBand'])

df_train.head()
```

This code throws following error which I cannot solve:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: Interval() < float()
```

Comment: Do you ever need the label's range? If not and they come from something like `pd.cut` then specify `labels=False` to get an integer label instead of the Interval.

Comment: @ALollz Thanks for your reply. That works and encodes these features right away.

Comment: Maybe someone can explain what caused the error and how to fix it if one needed to keep the intervals